# Obscure Probability Question

Tags: probability, statistics

> Suppose that blood chloride concentration (mmol/L) has a normal distribution with mean 104 and standard deviation 5 (information in the article “Mathematical Model of
>   Chloride Concentration in Human Blood,” J. of Med. Engr. and Tech., 2006: 25–30, including a normal probability plot as described in Section 4.6, supports this assumption).
>
> a.What is the probability that chloride concentration
>   equals 105? Is less than 105? Is at most 105?
>
> b.What is the probability that chloride concentration
>   differs from the mean by more than 1 standard deviation? Does this probability depend on the values of $\sigma$ and $\mu$
>
> c. How would you characterize the most extreme .1% of chloride concentration values?

I am having trouble with part c). I'm just not quite sure what it is asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you should find out the range of the lowest $0.05\%$ of all values, and similarily the range of the highest $0.05\%$ of all the values. The first range will have the form $(-\infty,a)$, and the second range will have the form $(b,\infty)$.

Comment: Do you possibly mean $ .05$\%? Are there an infinite amount of intervals?

Comment: I've edited my answer to address these points.

Comment: There are still an infinite amount of ranges though, right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "infinite of ranges". Both ranges do have infinite size. Is this what you mean?

Comment: From my understanding of the question, they want me to find range of values, such that the area of this range is $.1 \%$. Aren't there an infinite amount of intervals we could choose that would meet this specification?

Comment: I see. And yes, there are. But there is still the formulation "most extreme". For me, this suggests the interpretation I gave you in my answer.

Comment: There are indeed infinitely many pairs $(-b,a)$ such that $\Pr(Z\gt a)+\Pr(Z\lt -b)=0.001$. However, if we choose **symmetric** pairs $(-a,a)$ then there is only one value of $a$ that works. I have not done a detailed calculation, the cdf moves slowly around there. Something like $a=3.3$ works.